# Hive query output delimiter

Tags: hive, delimiter

I have 2 tables in Hive - first is external, the second one is managed. Managed table is populated from external using INSERT OVERWRITE...SELECT FROM external_table. Both tables are created with row delimited by ','. When I run selects queries into file, the delimiter in result file is Tab, but I need comma. How to change it to comma, I see no properties for that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, you need to change you field delimiter , not your line delimiter ie.

```
hive >> CREATE TABLE some_table 
        (col1 int,
         col2 int,
         col3 string)
        ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Secondly, if you still face this issue, you can simply change it using sed.

```
bash >> hive -e 'select * from some_Table' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > outputfile.txt
```

Please not that [\t] is to press Control+V and then the tab char:

```
sed 's/<Control+V><TAB character>/,/g'
```

Comment: thanks Nicole. But I thought that there is some config to set comma as a default output delimiter. Such hive's behaviour is strange...

Comment: Could you please brief me whats happening here - `sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > outputfile.txt`. `hive -e` is for running hive from command prompt, correct?

Comment: @RajaReddy `hive -e` executes a hive query. then the pipe passes the query output to `sed`. `sed` is a text manipulation program.  In this case the syntax `'s/[\t]/,/g'` has four sections separated by a `/`.  The first `s` means substitute. The `[\t]` is the match pattern for a tab. `,` is the replace value, and `g` means globally.