# Exporting the results of a hive script to a file without the logging info

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have been storing my hive queries in hql files and I usually run them using the following commands

```
$ nohup hive -i 'hivescript.hql' > results.tsv &
```

The problem is when I get the results back the file usually starts with logs and warnings from Hive. I am wondering if there is any command line argument that suppresses the log to just give me the results?

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to reroute the warnigns into another file

```
$ nohup hive -i 'hivescript.hql' 2> HiveLogs.txt 1>results.tsv &
```

This way you would get two files, one with just the results and another with just the logging information from Hive.