# How to extract 5k files out of HIVE tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I have a use case where i have all my 4 tb of data in HBase tables that i have interrogated with HIVE tables .

Now i want to extract 5 k files out of this 30 tables that i have created in HIVE.

This 5K files will be created by predefined 5K queries.
Can somebody suggest me what approach i should follow for this?
Required time for this is 15 hrs .

Should i write java code to generate all this files .

File generation is fast .Out of 5k text files there are 50 files that takes around 35 minutes rest of all creates very fast .

I have to generate zipped file and have to send it to client using ftp.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you can accomplish your task by first exporting the query results via one of methods from here : [How to export a Hive table into a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086642/how-to-export-a-hive-table-into-a-csv-file), compressing the files in a zip archive and then FTP'ing them. You can write a shell script to automate the process.