# Error while exporting the results of a HiveQL query to CSV?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am a beginner in Hadoop/Hive. I did some research to find out a way to export results of HiveQL query to CSV.
I am running below command line in Putty -

```
Hive -e ‘use smartsourcing_analytics_prod; select *  from solution_archive_data limit 10;’ > /home/temp.csv;
```

However below is the error I am getting[image]

```
ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'Hive' '-' 'e'
```

I would appreciate inputs regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Run your command from outside the hive shell - just from the linux shell.
- Run with '**h**ive' instead of '**H**ive'
- Just redirecting your output into csv file won't work. You can do:
  `hive -e 'YOUR QUERY HERE'  | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > sample.csv`
  like was offered here: [How to export a Hive table into a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086642/how-to-export-a-hive-table-into-a-csv-file)
- AkashNegi answer will also work for you... a bit longer though

Comment: The directory where the file - sample.csv is saved? I checked my user account folder but it is not there.

Comment: It will be saved in the location from which u run the command. Or you can redirect it to your desired location, for example /path/to/sample.csv. to find out where u r at run pwd command.

Answer (score 1):

One way I do such things is to create an external table with the schema you want. Then do INSERT INTO TABLE target_table ... Look at the example below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE isvaliddomainoutput (email_domain STRING, `count` BIGINT) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION "/user/cloudera/am/member_email/isvaliddomain";

INSERT INTO TABLE isvaliddomainoutput

SELECT * FROM member_email WHERE isvalid = 1;
```

Now go to "/user/cloudera/am/member_email/isvaliddomain" and find your data.

Hope this helps.