# Extract data from HDInsight/Hadoop as Excel/CSV to local machine using Data Lake Tools for ViS

Tags: csv, azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I have been trying to figure out how to extract data from a Hive table within HDInsight (for Windows) to my local machine as an Excel/CSV-file. For this purpose, I am using Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio.

Now I have tried to search for solutions and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086642/how-to-export-a-hive-table-into-a-csv-file) as well as this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual) after which I ended up with this query...

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY 'C:\Users\username\Documents' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;' SELECT * FROM hive_tablec;
```

When running this query, it actually runs successfully but doesn't show any files in the folder, after it has finished.

I also tried to adjust some of the queries suggested under the first link for my own purposes but this didn't yield any useful results, on the contrary (query here):

```
SELECT * FROM hive_tablec | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > 'C:\Users\username\Documents\';
```

Most of the queries which are upvoted in the first link and apparently work for others, seem written for console interfaces whereas I am using Data Lake Tools. Thus I am looking for a working query for that tool.

So my question is..., does anybody know of a feasible solution to this problem or is able to point out errors in my approach and query?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is extra " \" in below statement, which is unnecessary -

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\;'
```

just use

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your suggestion but this resulted in a "Failed" execution of the query. I subsequently ran the query I stated in my first post which again "Finished" but didn't create the file on local machine. So, I still am looking for a viable solution to this problem. If anybody has some input, please do tell. Thanks.