# How can I export csv data from hadoop (through hive in hue) using delimiter other than the comma?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

My question is in the title. In addition, hive `CLI` is not possible for my situation, with only the `hive` editor in the `hue` platform.
The reason why xlsx is not used is because only 30,000 records can be exported by xlsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below question. Lot of options are suggested by users.

[How to export a Hive table into a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086642/how-to-export-a-hive-table-into-a-csv-file)