# How can I export hive table with head to csv

Tags: csv, hive, hiveql

To export hive data to csv I use the following script:

> note that this is just a example:

```
#!/bin/bash
hive -e "insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/'
row format delimited fields terminated by ','
select * from Mydatabase,Mytable limit 10"
> /tmp/table.csv
```

I get a csv file in the local path: /tmp/, it looks like :

```
2017-07-04 12:58:05.0,MB0_CLI_2,29353,0982,SAIE,MNIT-BM,-,-
2017-07-04 12:56:07.0,MBUD00_CLI_2,629353,662982,SAE,MBEINIT-BM,-,-
2017-07-04 12:56:46.0,MBUDLI_2,618,65530,SAISIE,MBUIT-BA,-,-
2017-07-04 12:56:13.0,82_CLI_3,65082954,47857,UNAGE,-,PARERS,-
2017-07-04 12:56:05.0,822I_3,654,857,UNDGE,-,PAIRS,-
2017-07-04 12:59:28.0,823,65084,6926461,UNDNED_AAGE,-,PLIERS,-
2017-07-04 12:59:05.0,82200_CLI_3,65954,69461,UNNED_AFAGE,-,PULIERS,-
2017-07-04 12:56:46.0,MBUDLI_2,618,65530,SAISIE,MBUIT-BA,-,-
2017-07-04 12:56:13.0,82_CLI_3,65082954,47857,UNAGE,-,PARERS,-
2017-07-04 12:56:46.0,MBUDLI_2,618,65530,SAISIE,MBUIT-BA,-,-
```

The problem is that the csv file doesn't import the head of each column

how can I export hive table into csv file with the head of columns?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23944851/1319284

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I got this error : FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hive' '.' 'cli'

Comment: You can put more command separated by semi-colon. I do it this way: hive -S -e 'set hive.execution.engine=tez; set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from tableName'  etc etc..

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way. You can put more command by separating it by semi-colon. Sed is a command to change , to blank and tabs (default separator) to comma. The result is a csv file named; tableName.csv.

```
hive -e 'set hive.execution.engine=tez; set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from <TableName>' | sed 's/,/ /g' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > /tmp/tableName.csv
```

Comment: the script works, but it doesn't give me the heads!!!

Comment: I edited my answer, pls try it.

Comment: You think the problem comes from separator?

Comment: I think the command "insert overwrite" does not accept another command.

Comment: "insert overwrite" deletes the existing csv files, I think

Comment: did the updated answer worked for you? If yes, pls upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: I test your update answer, but it doesn't work for me, BTW Thanks*