# Writing result set without iteration over rows in hive jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, apache-nifi

Hi I am trying to fetch big table from hive and then write a csv file . Is there any way where we can write the whole result set in one go in a file as iteration over rows for a table containing several millions of records takes time .

I dont want to do while(rs.next()).

Comment: Some DBMSes support writing to a csv file in their SQL language, but if you have a `ResultSet`, you will have to iterate it.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086642/how-to-export-a-hive-table-into-a-csv-file

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the SQL environment but usually you can just use SQL like so:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME]
  INTO OUTFILE '[FILENAME]'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

For Hive it should be similar to the following

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '[FILENAME]' 
SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME]
```

I can't be more specific on how to exactly separate fields since i have no access to Hive but the documentaion on this should help

[Writing data into the filesystem from queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML)