# how to print out and save the result of the query in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make connection to a remote Hive cluster using python. I tried pyhive, pyhs2 but had no success. With the below code, I am able to connect to hive but how can I print and save the result in a panda data frame?

I have tried the below lines without any luck:
out = stdout.read()
print stdout.read()

```
import os
import paramiko


ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.connect('00.00.00.00.', username='******', password='*******')
sshin, sshout, ssherr= ssh.exec_command('hive -e "select * from t1"')
```

I want to print and save the result in a pandas data frame.

Comment: what problem are you facing with Pyhive? You can easily make a connection to hive using Pyhive also. see answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57157942/access-tables-from-impala-through-python/57168447#57168447

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean load the results in a pandas `DataFrame` then, first save it locally

```
hive -e "select * from t1" > /home/yourfile.tsv
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086642/how-to-export-a-hive-table-into-a-csv-file) answer.

Then load it into a DataFrame like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/home/yourfile.tsv",delimiter = "\t")
```