# python connect to hive with pyhive get error

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

When I used pyhive to connect the hive service get error, this is my operation step

I start hive service with command below

```
hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10001
hive --service metastore
```

Then used Pyhive to create connection

```
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host='localhost', port=10001, database='default')
```

But I get error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 199, in __init__
    _check_status(response)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 495, in _check_status
    raise OperationalError(response)
pyhive.exc.OperationalError: 
TOpenSessionResp(status=TStatus(statusCode=3, infoMessages=['*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Failed to open new session:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): 
User: admin is not allowed to impersonate admin:14:13', 
'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager:createSession:SessionManager.java:419', 
'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager:openSession:SessionManager.java:362', 
'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:openSessionWithImpersonation:CLIService.java:193', 
xxxxxxorg.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): 
User: admin is not allowed to impersonate admin'), serverProtocolVersion=9, sessionHandle=None, configuration=None)
```

What can I do to resolve this problem? thanks.

Comment: Where's ur hive.connect? May this help.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57157942/access-tables-from-impala-through-python/57168447#57168447

Comment: It can not work for me in that answer. I run that command at the python script, and hiveserver2 also python script are run at the same machine.