# Hive output to a text file in a comma separated format

Tags: hive

I am executing the following

```
hive -e 'select product_id from table;' > out.txt
```

This is giving me a text file with each product id on each line. I want them to be on one line with commas in between each id. I even tried to use shell scripting to get the desired format.

```
paste -s -d ',' < out.txt
```

Using this command I am getting the result on the terminal in the right format. But the file is not getting modified. Ideally, shouldn't this be possible by setting some hive configuration.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702476/hive-query-output-delimiter) SO question. But it did not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sed -i 'N;s/\n/,/' filename
```

Your question heading was misleading, as per the question heading,

For Hive versions 0.11.0 and above,

```
  INSERT OVERWRITE [LOCAL] DIRECTORY 'dirname' 
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    <your query>;
```

Reference : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries

is yet another solution to create csv from hive query results.

Comment: The file did get modified. But it is now looking like this
1,2\n
3,4\n
4,5

Comment: If that is the case, are there any extra chars in the initial file? 
paste -s -d ',' < out.txt > out1.txt should work. There is no workaround in hive config changes to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is out there somewhere, but I am giving you my answer which I use on a regular basis in hive output to csv. This works like charm and you can also put a complex query into a file and use the below code:

```
hive -e 'select * from table' | sed 's/[\t]/~/g' > output.csv
hive -f /tmp/myhql.hql | sed 's/[\t]/~/g' > output.csv
```

Comment: See you? Formatting things is very easy here, and goodlooking content attracts upvotes. Upvotes are our collective money, sex and drug here, soon you will be also addict. :-) (Btw, thanks the good content!)