# How to get column name in Hive when outputting the query (and not table_name.column_name)

Tags: csv, hive, header

Using Hive I would like to get the result of a query inside a csv file, I would also like to get the header.

To achieve this I'm executing:

```
hive -e '
    use database;
    set hive.cli.print.header=true;
    select * from table;
' > /home/centos/user/result.csv
```

But the first line of the csv is:

```
table.field1_name,table.field2_name,table.field3_name
```

How can I get insead:

```
field1_name,field2_name,field3_name
```

Answer (score 15):

I just needed to add:

```
set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false;
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding an explanation of why this works.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` will do the job.

Suppose `fun.csv` contains the following:

```
table.field1_name,table.field2_name,table.field3_name
```

Then I do the following in the command line:

```
sed -e 's/table.//g' < fun.csv > fun2.csv
```

Now `fun2.csv` has:

```
field1_name,field2_name,field3_name
```

Comment: yeah I know I can do this, but i suppose a hive option is availabe

Comment: @user3636476 glad you find solution but one liner wouldn't hurt I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use select column1,column2 from tablename instead of select * from tablename, in that case tablename will not be added into the column name.
In that case need not give sed command.

Answer (score -1):

I use

```
hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from database.table;' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /your_path_to_csv
```

It works well for me.

Reference:
[Hive query output delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702476/hive-query-output-delimiter)